# How does a user get the "delete question" privilege?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I recently asked a question about a possible oddity of Python documentation.

It was a legitimate question and in fact one of the comments to the question was very helpful and could be for others.

Someone then came along and got the question deleted. I don't know who that was.

Can someone with a certain rep just do this on their own (the question stood at -3 at the time I believe), or do they need the collaboration of a mod?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58419208/where-if-anywhere-do-i-find-comprehensive-documentation-for-python) is the (now deleted) question.

Comment: Forget about "who" deleted the question.  Concentrate more on "why".

Comment: @Snow Fair comment. So a) how can I find that out and b) what if I disagree?

Comment: Did you check the "deleted recent questions" link in your profile (activity -> questions then scroll down)? Although, asking *why* it was deleted is probably more constructive.

Comment: If it wasn't answered, and was downvoted, there's a fair chance no-one did, and it got cleaned up by the roomba instead. See [This post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/369403) for details

Comment: [Why and how are some questions deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions). From the Help Center.

Comment: @JeanneDark OK thanks.  Yes I found out who deleted it. I'm interested to know who has the authority to do that.

Comment: Users with more than 10k can cast "delete votes". See the links above.

Comment: @yivi Thanks.  That was the main thing I wanted to know.  Will check links.

Comment: Users with more than 20k can vote to delete without having to wait 48hs. [More info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222).

Comment: There are also several comments on the question explaining why it is off-topic. Discussing whether the python documentation philosophy should change is really nothing you can discuss on SO. Given that the question already attracted a low quality answer, deleting it seems to be a reasonable thing.

Comment: You may want to rephrase this question to *Why was my question closed and deleted?*, because the general question *Why can certain users delete questions* is a duplicate and answer by "Get the 10k deletion privilege".

Comment: @Adriaan The wording/intent of the question here has already been edited first by me and then by someone else :).

Comment: @BDL In fact it is acknowledged there that it is not off-topic, and it isn't. The question started as a purely practical one, from an observation that it was unlike Java documentation, i.e. to understand how the `os` functions work it appears you have to start at the top of the page and see the stuff about `os.OSError`, as revealed by Chrispresso's first comment. The fact that I find that unsatisfactory in itself, and in fact not giving enough detail even when you know it, is something which arose in a second stage.

Comment: @mikerodent Sorry, but I can't find any comment on the question which acknowledges that the question is on-topic. Neither the question "Where is it documented" nor "Should the documentation be updated" are on-topic. The first one asks for an off-site resource. The other one is not about programming at all. What's the point of discussing the policies of some other community here on SO? Also, the edit war on your question because you refused to remove meta text is also not helping your case.

Comment: Noise like "Please read the question before down-voting. Thanks." should never be added to any post. It won't do you any favor or prevent someone from downvoting.

Comment: @BDL The primary source of a language's definitive documentation is most definitely on-topic in my view and has everything to do with programming. It's funny how "how do you check whether a list is empty in Python" can attract a vote of (at this writing) 3235, while something about a legitimate wish to understand how Python handles a non-existent file, **from the authoritative source**, is considered (by you and others) off-topic.

Comment: @mikerodent Asking how a specific method handles non-existing files **is on topic** - But that's not what you were asking. Note that there is a huge difference between "How does `os.remove()` handle non-existing files" and "Where do I find the documentation about what `os.remove()` does when handling non-existing files". You asked the second one.

Comment: @BDL Well in fact I had found out the question to the first question, as I said in the 2nd para of the question, by my own experimentation. I was then bemused by the fact of this absence of documentation in the relevant Python 3.6.x page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Who can delete questions?

From the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) on reaching 10,000 reputation:

> Access to moderator tools
>
> Privilege type: Moderation privilege
>
> Awarded at: 10,000 reputation
>
> (...)
>
> #### Deleting questions
>
> Users with this reputation level can delete closed questions.
>
> (...)
>
> You must wait for a question to be closed for **2** days before you can vote for deletion. This restriction is removed for [trusted users](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) when a post scores **-3** or lower. If you feel a post should be deleted despite having lots of votes or for being new, please [**flag** it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) for community moderator attention.

Thus, any user with more than 10k reputation can vote to delete a closed question, provided it is closed for more than 2 days. Users with 20k reputation can vote to delete immediately after closure, if the post is at -3 or lower aggregate score.

Answer (score 13):

I kicked off the delete cycle on this question. I believed it was off-topic, and you entered into an edit war to add hostile commentary on the closure, as can be seen in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58419208/revisions). Since it was being bumped to the front page several times unnecessarily, and since the content being added was not diplomatic, I believed deletion was justified.

The specific close reason in this case was:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

If you have a question that has been closed and you believe it should be reopened, asking a (diplomatic) question on Meta is a good way to handle it. You can also add comments under the question, but Meta is probably a more effective approach.

It is possible that this question can be undeleted and made on-topic, with a view to starting a reopen vote process. It would need to have two things removed:

- request for external resources
- hostile meta commentary

I believe you can edit it while it is deleted, so if you wish to do that, please go ahead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It's what I thought might have happened. I still think it was on-topic (= all about the primary source for a programming language's usage specification) and legitimate. I should however have anticipated the knee-jerk downvotes. I still consider that the Python documentation, for the `os` module at least, is not adequate or sufficient, and will  unnecessarily confuse those starting on their Python journey.

Comment: @mikerodent "I still consider that the Python documentation, for the os module at least, is not adequate or sufficient, and will unnecessarily confuse those starting on their Python journey" Before you start editing... Given the explicit questions in the deleted post, what kind of *answer* are you thinking you should get, here on Stack Overflow? The first is asking whether people agree/disagree - that would make it off-topic as "primarily opinion-based". Just having people agree/disagree on SO is not going to get anything changed and is not going to help future users of the site... [1/1]

Comment: [2/1] Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository to help people solve specific problems, not a discussion forum/venue. The second question - " If the documentation is silent about this are we meant to assume the return is None? " - could be legitimate. Then there's a third question - "Are we just expected to work things out by trial and error (and maybe make our own notes)?" - that, again, would mostly be discussion. These kinds of things would maybe be OK in a topical *chat room*, but as Q&A don't fit the site profile.

Comment: "I still think it was on-topic (= all about the primary source for a programming language's usage specification) " - that's the thing: how can folks on Stack Overflow have any influence on that? They can't, so that's why it's not on-topic.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks for these thoughtful comments. I hadn't in fact intended editing the question or trying to revive it. It should have been enough to see the value of the question just to have seen the first comment by Chrispresso, about `os.OSError` at the top of the `os` page. But no, the consensus is to prefer to downvote, put on hold and then delete. I get the message. I don't think it serves Python learners, but this is clearly a minority view.

Comment: @Mikerodent "the Python learners".... but Stack isn't meant to *teach* new programmers. It's meant to be a repository of knowledge. If the intent is to "teach".... it belongs in a blog, or on a website somewhere (for sure, if it's helpful to new python learners, it belongs somewhere). Maybe not Stack :/

Comment: @Patrice Thanks. That's an interesting angle. Is it really true that SO is not intended to teach? As I take my first steps in CPython 3 (I've used Jython - v2 - in the past) I'm constantly googling and constantly getting links to SO questions: I'm learning and SO appears to be the thing teaching me. Of course maybe that is not the *intention*. But the intention of each individual who poses a question is to learn, i.e. be taught :), I'd have thought ... ?

Comment: @Mike Stack isn't intended to teach. Stack is intended to be a high quality, low noise to signal ratio, repository of coding knowledge. What you present is the main issue Stack is faced these days: People first interact with Stack through "research, find stack, learn", then it becomes easy to go "oh stack is for learning!". No (and no blame to you. The site does a piss-poor job of setting expectations correctly...). Stack builds an encyclopedia. People who read the encyclopedia learn. But the curators aren't teaching. They are... curating the content of the encyclopedia (if I make sense?)

Comment: I think you *do* make sense. :)

Comment: @mikerodent: "the consensus is to prefer to downvote, put on hold and then delete" - these are independent variables. Normally for an off-topic question we put it on hold, we don't delete it, and it may not be downvoted. For a spectacularly lazy question all three will happen. Yours was not in that category though - it was an ordinary off-topic question, and the downvotes probably were caused by the noisy edits, and the same for the deletion. It would not normally have been deleted manually (some questions are deleted by the system automatically though).

Comment: @halfer thanks.  While you're there, what on earth is the reason for your latest edit to this meta question, i.e. removing the "[errant question]" in the title and putting the little phrase about wanting to delete at the bottom instead of the top. People are arguably wasting their lives reading the question now and continuing to downvote. I couldn't care less about the continuing downvotes, by the way, but I'd prefer people not to be wasting their time.

Comment: @mikerodent: I have four relevant pieces of advice here. Firstly, we do not "tag" or "label" titles if a question is [solved] or [withdrawn] or whatever. The title is _just_ a description of what the question is. Secondly, questions are not really withdrawn on Meta - perhaps someone else will find it useful? Thirdly, your question of "what on earth is the reason" (as opposed to "what is the reason") suggests you are still outraged about the mutual editing and voting facilities here. Please don't be - those facilities are normal operation on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Fourthly, updates should always go in chronological order (new ones at the bottom) otherwise new readers will have a hard time understanding what you are saying (they will have to read in reverse order).

Comment: For what it is worth, downvotes don't mean much on Meta - they are a signal about community opinion, but they do not reduce your reputation points.

Comment: No I'm not outraged. I just find some of these conventions rather Byzantine. I think this question should just be pickled in order for others not to be wasting time on it, as I suggested. Thanks for spending your own precious time giving me the low-down though.

Comment: @mikerodent: we don't mind, really. We are here because that's what we do, same as on the main site. The conventions make sense eventually - most of them are based on the principles of technical writing. The main frustration we get is that a few people don't want Q&A, they want a chat room - and sadly we have to disappoint!

Comment: (If you want to get rid of this Meta question, you can try casting a close vote - "unclear" would be fine. But it is not a bother to leave it open).

Answer (score 6):

You're asking who can delete questions, but ironically, that is explained in [Stack Overflow's documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges).

What you implicitly seem to be complaining about though (and explicitly in your original questions and comments under it), is why people downvoted and closevoted it.

That's because your question is little more than a rant (*"why didn't they document this"*) and a request for off-site resources (*"where to find comprehensive documentation"*). Both are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and therefore it was treated as such.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the wording of this meta question has changed a couple of times since I posed it. In future I shall make reference to the SO documentation, of course. I explained in the original question how it came about:  I found out what happens when `os.remove()` tries to operate on a non-existent file by experimentation, and was then bemused at what I consider the inadequate way this is documented, in the case of the `os` module at least. In reality many questions on SO rightly relate to the definitive usage resources for a language, and rightly are not considered off-topic.

Comment: I tried to explain in my answer why your question is off-topic. You can then argue that other questions are on-topic, but that doesn't make your question any less off-topic. Look, _"How do I do X?"_ is on-topic, _"Where can I find X?"_ is off-topic.

Comment: I just disagree (that "Where can I find comprehensive Python documentation?" is off-topic). It's a controversial way of expressing it, but that expression follows on with simple logic from my experience of finding that the widely accepted official source of usage documentation doesn't tell you everything you need to know. Someone somewhere might actually have put together an adequate guide through an app which parsed through the source code, for all I knew.

Comment: The fact that you're desperately looking for something, and even that it might be helpful for many people, does not mean that asking about such a thing is on-topic for Stack Overflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam"_. I get it, the Python docs suck, but that's not something you can complain about here; it's just not constructive.